# How to make \simeq downward?

Tags: xy-pic

I am trying to use xy-pic to typeset a downward \simeq, but it seems that the symbol is too small. I would appreciate very much if anybody can help me.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "down" -- should the symbol be rotated 30, 45, 60 or 90 degrees?

Comment: I used $\xymatrix{A\ar@{}[d]^\simeqd}\ar[r]&B}$, where $\simeqd$ is the rotation of $\simeq$ by 90 degree.

Comment: And which package do you load to get the (insufficiently large) `\simeqd` macro? Or do you perform the rotation manually, say, via a `\rotatebox` directive.

Comment: I used \rotatebox to define \simeqd.

Comment: So what do you mean by "too small"? Since your macro performs a rotation, the symbol's size is exactly equal to that of `\simeq`...

Comment: I want it to match the size of arrows in the diagram.

Comment: I can't get your instructions `$\xymatrix{A\ar@{}[d]^\simeqd}\ar[r]&B}$` to compile. (The error message: `! Xy-pic error: in entry "1,1": No [d] (is "2,1") from here.`) Please tell us which package(s) you load in your document.

Comment: I only wrote the first line just now, the correct one is $\xymatrix{A\ar@{}[d]^\simeqd\ar[r]&B}\\C\ar[r]&D}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$\xymatrix{A\ar@{}[d]^\simeqd\ar[r]&B}\\C\ar[r]&D}$.` doesn't compile either.

Comment: Sorry. It should be $\xymatrix{A\ar@{}d]^\simeqd\ar[r]&B\\C\ar[r]&D}$.

Answer (score 3):

Too small in what sense?

You can get $\simeq$ rotated by doing the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\simeqd}{\mathrel{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\simeq$}}}

\begin{document}
$\simeqd$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\rotatebox` is defined in the `graphics`and `graphicx`packages.  I’d recommend the latter one, see `grfguide.pdf`.

Comment: @Moss_the_TeXie - See the edited version of the code. (The `rotating` package automatically loads `graphicx`. I agree it's cleaner to load `graphicx` directly.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `xy` (**XY-pic**) package, adding the `scalerel` package (with the command `\scaleobj{<scale-dimension>}`) and a rotate macro symbol `\vsimeq` and `\vvsimeq` you could increase the size of the simeq symbol in the size you like.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\vsimeq}{\scaleobj{2}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\simeq$}}}
\newcommand{\vvsimeq}{\scaleobj{1}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\simeq$}}}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix{ 
A \ar[d]^{\vsimeq} &\\
B &}\quad \xymatrix{ 
A \ar[d]^{\vvsimeq} &\\
B &}
\end{document}
```